# Handle a associative array passed from PHP in Java

Tags: php, jsp

Hi I am trying to send an associative array to a JSP servlet in a POST request. How do I handle that array in the servlet. Can I even do it? I just want to convert that assoc array in to a hashset/table in  JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to POST some JSON and then consume the JSON in the servlet. The [Jackson library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) can unmarshall JSON to a HashMap (or equiv) with one line of code.

If you provide us with some example data then i could suggest some code...

Comment: Yeah this should work, but was wondering if at all java can handle that associative array. I guess the answer is no then.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. A PHP associative array is a native data format to PHP and although its similar to a Java HashMap, you can't transfer a native data structure over a webservice call. You either have to translate your associative array to request parameters (e.g. key1=value1&key2=value2) OR encode your data structure into some common encocded format, such as JSON (or XML, ProtoBuf, etc). Then on the Java end you have to unencode that transfer format back to the native data structure.

Comment: don't know which part of it you did not understand cause you seem to have answered it pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - poor choice of words, you got me there :)